# I'm using toString method, but it doesn't give me the format I want?

Tags: java

I want my method to return a rectangle base(coordinates) height and width.

An example

For the rectangle with a lower left corner located at (-3, 2)
and having a width of 4 and a height of 5, the method should return exactly
“base: (-3,2) w:4 h:5”. For this example, there is a single space at location 5, 12, and 16.

//left = x, bottom =y , width = w, height = h

this is the method I have

```
public String toString(){
    return String.format("%-5s%-12s%16d","base:" ,"(",this.left,",", this.bottom,")", "w:",this.width, "h:",this.height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a coalition between the number of format specifiers and the number of parameters, they should be equal in quality.

Something like `String.format("%-5s(%d, %d) w:%d h:%d","base:", left, bottom, width, height)` will print `base:(-3, 2) w:4 h:5` ... based on the values you have provided

The format specifiers are based on C, have a look at [these examples](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this function is to put all the text you want to display in the first parameter of String.format().

Like this:

```
public String toString(){
        return String.format("base:(%d,%d) w:%d h:%d", this.left, this.bottom, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're interpolating several constant strings into a constant format string. Could you confirm that that's what you really want?

Also, I count several more arguments passed to `String.format` than there are format specifiers. Get that sorted out first. By then, it should be clearer why the output you're getting isn't matching what you want.

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is the output i get is only number 5, which is "this.left" What im trying to do is out put the integers out of those fields into  toString Method so how can i do that ?

Comment: The reason you only see up to the 5 is in how `String.format` works. It looks through the first argument, the format string, and does what the format string asks. Whenever there is a specifier, it takes the next argument passed to it and includes it in the output. You've provided several arguments, but the format specifier doesn't ask for them.

Comment: Ooooh, but then how can i do that ? all arguments formatted with spaces indicated ? I tried looking or a solution i cant find it , someone help please

Comment: That's a good comment but as it's written now, it's not an answer. Try to make your statements more definitive rather than suggestions and include a code snippet showing what you mean and it will be an answer.

Comment: If you already know `String.format` is the best solution, you just have to add more format specifiers. But from what it looks like, you might be able to get what you want with string concatenations. To start you off, try doing `"(" + this.left + "." + this.top + ")"`. See if you can extend that to achieve your desired output.